# Pandas: how to append many rows to dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to grab some historical data from binance (exchange, API) and I'm using their modules. I can get the data but whenever is use the code below it creates 0's and new lines for the 'close' and 'volume':

```
ticker = 'NANOETH'
interv = "1d"
period = "1M"
rest_client.klines(ticker, period)
klines = rest_client.klines(symbol=ticker, interval=interv)
df=[]

for kline in klines:
    df=[kline.open_time, kline.open, kline.high,kline.low, kline.close, kline.volume]
    df = pd.DataFrame([df], columns = ["Open Time","Close Time","Open","High","Low","Close", "Volume"])



    print (df)
```

The output is:

```
       Open Time     Close Time        Open        High         Low  \
0  1517529600000  1517615999999  0.02010000  0.02998700  0.01764600   

        Close           Volume  
0  0.01841200  448361.60000000  
       Open Time     Close Time        Open        High         Low  \
0  1517616000000  1517702399999  0.01848800  0.01890000  0.01600300   

        Close           Volume  
0  0.01700900  410642.17000000  
       Open Time     Close Time        Open        High         Low  \
0  1517529600000  1517615999999  0.02010000  0.02998700  0.01764600   

        Close           Volume  
0  0.01841200  448361.60000000
```

I would like it to look like:

```
    Open Time     Close Time        Open        High         Low     Close           Volume   
1517529600000  1517615999999  0.02010000  0.02998700  0.01764600  0.01841200  448361.60000000
1517616000000  1517702399999  0.01848800  0.01890000  0.01600300  0.01700900  410642.17000000  
1517529600000  1517615999999  0.02010000  0.02998700  0.01764600  0.01841200  448361.60000000
```

And would also like to index the first date and covert it to an actual datetime.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a list of lists via a list comprehension. Then feed into `pd.DataFrame` as a final step.

```
lst = [[k.open_time, k.open, k.high, k.low, k.close, k.volume] for kline in klines]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['Open Time', 'Close Time', 'Open',
                                'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `type` the object `klines` is but I'm assuming it's a `pd.DataFrame`.  You could subset it like this in the future:

```
# Get the indicies you want
idx_want = ["open_time", "open", "high", "low", "close", "volume"]
# Subset the pd.DataFrame (asseuming klines is a dataframe
df_subset = klines.loc[:,idx_want]
# If klines is a list of pd.Series then do `klines = pd.DataFrame(klines)`
# Relabel Columns
df_subset.columns = ['Open Time', 'Close Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your code also but I'm getting an 'EOL while scanning string literal ' on the idx_want in the df_subset. I placed your code under the for kline statement. Have I done something wrong:

Comment: Can you do type(klines)